# Animation system with generics can't use polymorphism

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an animation system that affects different types so I thought I would use generics.

I have an animation controller that gets all animation objects into a collection (or at least that was the plan) then then run the animation on all the animation objects.

The problem is I can't do it this way in C# as it does not allow polymorphic collections for different types on generics.

Here is the code structure involved for different animations:

```
public abstract class Animation<T> {
    protected T TargetValue {protected set; get;}  // could be int/float/vector2 etc etc
    protected T StartValue {protected set; get;} 
    public T CurrentValue {protected set; get;} 
    public Action OnUpdate;

    public virtual T Animate(float deltaTime) => OnUpdate?.Invoke();
}

public class Fade : Animation<float> { // lerp between two floats

   public override float Animate(float deltaTime) {
      CurrentValue = float.Lerp(StartValue,TargetValue,deltaTime);
      base.Animate(deltaTime);
   }

}

public class Translation : Animation<Vector2> { // move to target Vector2
   public override Vector2 Animate(float deltaTime) {
       CurrentValue = Vector2.Lerp(StartValue,TargetValue,deltaTime);  
       base.Animate(deltaTime); 
   }
}
```

Now my animation controller class is supposed to get all animations an run animations on them:

```
public class AnimationController {
   
    private List<Animation<???>> _animations = new List<Animation<???>>();    
    void Init() => _animations = GetAllComponents<Animation>(); // get all animations as collection


    public void Animation(float deltaTime)
       for(int i = 0; i < _animations.Count; i++) 
          _animations[i].Animate(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

However, this is not an option for me as I cannot have collections of generics with different types for the generic `T`.

So what would be a better design for this system because I do not know a good solution ???

Comment: Your `Animate()` methods have different return types. It doesn't look like you're actually using the return values though ... can you remove it or make the return type consistent and have `Animate<T>` implement an interface?

Comment: Well the type is defined by the derived class's T type. So they only return what ever <T> will be. Which is why i chose generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach One

Each concrete implementation of `Animation` appears to be used by other classes in different ways:

- At the minimum, `Animation` items need to be stored in a collection.
- There is a need to call the `Animation.Animate(float)` method on each item in the collection. This caller (which processes the collection) does not need to be aware of the type of state parameters (time-varying variables).
- Each `Animation` item may also be used by some other classes (which are not illustrated in the code example above). Each of these other classes make use of the state parameters (time-varying variables) of some specific concrete `Animation` items; therefore, they must be aware of the types.

Suggestion (C# specific. The suggestion may need to be tailored or modified for other languages.)

Firstly, define an `Animation` interface or abstract class that is non-generic.

```
public interface Animation
{
    void Animate(float deltaTime);
}
```

Then, define a generic `Animation` interface where the types of time-varying variables are specified.

```
public interface Animation<T> : Animation
{
    T CurrentValue { get; }
}
```

Finally, have your abstract classes implement `Animation<T>`. By doing so, they also indirectly implement `Animation` (the non-generic interface), which allows the `AnimationController` to call its `void Animate(float)` method even if `AnimationController` doesn't know the types of each item's time-varying variables.

This is a very common usage pattern in C# generics.

---

Summary of Approach One

In C#, it is widely recognized that generic classes may require some kind of uniform handling in which the generic parameters (the `<T>`) don't matter and shouldn't matter. To do so, the widely-accepted practice is to create a parent interface or parent abstract class that is non-generic, that provides limited access to the concrete classes, without the knowledge of the `<T>`.

---

Approach Two

Provide an abstraction for the concrete implementations of time-varying variables (`float`, `Vector2`, etc). Let's call it `Lerpable`.

The `Lerpable` interface will have a method called `Lerp`.

Comment: I use approach #1 all the time - as it turns out I was just mucking about in some code today related to that very pattern. In my case I had something like a `Job<T>` that depended on an expression tree of `T`, but then I wanted to compile the tree and invoke an `IJob` generically from a list.